# Actionable Message (Message Card) Input Value Substitution not working in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors, card

I have a problem where I am unable to retrieve values from the message card text input in Microsoft Teams, but the same JSON template actually works on [Message Card Playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/).

A brief overview of my Microsoft Card implementation. I have to use MessageCard as I am using connectors (incoming webhook) to send a card to Microsoft Teams. Thus, the input value substitution syntax is referred from [Message Card Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#actioncard-action) - ***{{<id of input>.value}}***. I am not getting any value using this syntax in my Message Card when I am in TEAMS. E.g. User filled in a textbox, and the value is not being captured or cannot be retrieved with this syntax.

The card that I used is as followed:

```
{
"@type":  "MessageCard",
"@context":  "http://schema.org/extensions",
"themeColor":  "0076D7",
"summary":  "{{ctx.monitor.name}}",
"sections":  [
                 {
                     "activityTitle":  "![TestImage](https://47a92947.ngrok.io/Content/Images/default.png){{ctx.monitor.name}}",
                     "activitySubtitle":  "Alert",
                     "activityImage":  "https://teamsnodesample.azurewebsites.net/static/img/image5.png",
                     "facts":  [
                                   {
                                       "name":  "Assigned to",
                                       "value":  "Sam"
                                   }
                               ],
                     "markdown":  true
                 }
             ],
"potentialAction":  [
                        {
                            "@type": "ActionCard",
                            "name": "Add a comment",
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "@type": "TextInput",
                                    "id": "comment",
                                    "title": "Enter your comment",
                                    "isMultiline": true
                                }
                            ],
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                                    "name": "OK",
                                    "target": "https://webhook.site/ab592c11-4590-438d-90c2-57bc4bb4aa8a?serviceToken=d2l0cy1zYW06MXFhekBXU1g%3D",
                                    "body": "{{comment.value}}"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
}
```

Note: You can see there is *"summary":  "{{ctx.monitor.name}}"*, it is a property from Kibana (a data visualization tool). This value works, but it is not our focus right here. My problem is I cannot get any value from {{comment.value}}, it is an empty string.

My questions are:

1. Is this the limitation coming from MSFT Teams itself?

Comment: Currently web hook does not support Action card. Could you please check this docs for more [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using)? Could you please try using  adaptive card or message card instead of action card? try if that helps.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I am confused by your message, referring to [Message Card Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#actions), i am unable to use adaptive card as i am sending message via connector. I am using message card in my case. And action card is part of the actions from message card.

Comment: We are able to reproduce the issue at our end. Raised a bug.

Answer (score 0):

@csamleong could you please replace the "body": "comment ={{comment.value}}" so you will receive the comment value:
card json:

```
{
"summary": "Card \"Test card\"",
"themeColor": "0078D7",
"@type":  "MessageCard",
"@context":  "http://schema.org/extensions",
"themeColor":  "0076D7",
"summary":  "{{ctx.monitor.name}}",
"sections":  [
                 {
                     "activityTitle":  "![TestImage](https://47a92947.ngrok.io/Content/Images/default.png){{ctx.monitor.name}}",
                     "activitySubtitle":  "Alert",
                     "activityImage":  "https://teamsnodesample.azurewebsites.net/static/img/image5.png",
                     "facts":  [
                                   {
                                       "name":  "Assigned to",
                                       "value":  "Sam"
                                   }
                               ],
                     "markdown":  true
                 }
             ],
"potentialAction":  [
                        {
                            "@type": "ActionCard",
                            "name": "Add a comment",
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "@type": "TextInput",
                                    "id": "comment",
                                    "title": "Enter your comment",
                                    "isMultiline": true
                                }
                            ],
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                                    "name": "OK",
                                    "target": "https://daf47bb241c6.ngrok.io//weatherforecast/Configure/Comment",
                                    "body": "comment={{comment.value}}"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
}
```

Post Method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("Configure/Comment")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Comment()
        {
            string bodyStr;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(this.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
            {
                bodyStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            string comment = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bodyStr) ? string.Empty : bodyStr.Split('=')[1];
            Response.Headers.Add("CARD-UPDATE-IN-BODY", "true");
            return null;
        }
```

You will receive value in the comment varable.